# breeze breeze.EntityQuery.from('Agencies'); returns the last entity returned for entire results

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, breeze, hottowel

Let me start by saying i'm new to breeze so I apologize if this turns out to be a stupid error on my side.

I'm using angular specifically John Papa's hot towel base. I have create a repository that returns back a list of agencies from a WebApi2 service (backed by EF6). This code actually seems to work fine if i break point the return of the breeze httpget the records returned show all the correct entity data and count.

The problem is when they are returned to my angular callback from "... .execute().then" the number if items is correct but all the entities appear to be the last entity returned from the webapi.

I am using local storage again John Papa's zStorage. but even if i by pass the local call and force just a remote it's the same result.

So any ideas and what code snippets are needed to help resolve this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please provide codes to better understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was an error in camelCasing between the database, server and client. Once I got the "Id" fields all in sync things started working properly.